# How to get value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, dom, contact-form-7

Let's see https://sisschools.org/contact-us-3/

Choose your recipient and Please Specify Your Reicipient.

If I select except SIS Bona Vista, then beside column is hidden. But it's not work.

```
    <div class="edgt-grid-col-6"><label>Choose your recipient </label>
                [select* select-a-schools id:SelectSchools "SIS Bona Vista" "SIS Kelapa Gading" "SIS Pantai Indah Kapuk" "SIS Cilegon" "SIS Semarang" "SIS Palembang" "SIS Medan"]
        </div>

<div id="SelectBv" class="edgt-grid-col-6">
<label> Please Specify Your Reicipient </label>
[select* select-a-bv include_blank "Techer" "Student" "General"] 
</div>
```

This is JavaScipt code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// Show the Text field by default
document.getElementById('SelectBv').style.display = 'true';
document.getElementById('SelectSchools').addEventListener('change', displayTextField);
function displayTextField() {
  // Get the value of the currently selected dropdown. 'select-a-schools' is the name of the dropdown you specify in the form builder
  var cmbSchool = document.querySelector('input[name="select-a-schools"]:select').value;
  if (cmbSchool == 'SIS Bona Vista') {
    document.getElementById('SelectBv').style.display = 'true';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('SelectBv').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: explain the problem clearly

Comment: I don't think a select has an input tag, just a select tag

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand your question, but you could use `document.getElementsByClassName("styledSelect")[0].innerHTML` to get the selected value of the dropdown box, so it would look like the following...

```
document.getElementById('SelectBv').style.display = 'true';
document.getElementById('SelectSchools').addEventListener('change', displayTextField);
function displayTextField() {
  var cmbSchool = document.getElementsByClassName("styledSelect")[0].innerHTML;
  if (cmbSchool == "SIS Bona Vista") {
    document.getElementById('SelectBv').style.display = 'true';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('SelectBv').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: `style.display = 'true';` - please, no.

Comment: I did not change any of his code except to add one line. I did not try to improve anything else but his issue.

Comment: I believe I  noticed that.